# Opening the result of GET-request with data in a new tab

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I am struggling to find a way in Ajax and JQuery to make a GET-request with data parameters, and to render the response in a new tab in the browser. Something like this:

```
$('#test-button').on('click', function(e){
    var data = {'some_param': [1,2,55,44,3]}
    $.get('/test_url/', data, function(html_response) {
        // render the HTML contained in html_response in a new tab
    });
});
```

Comment: Most browsers if not all would block it because you call it from an async callback

Comment: Why bother using ajax instead of just a link -  `<a href='/test_url/?some_param=12322' target='_blank'>click me</a>`

Comment: Well, what if my data would contain an array of values like in the updated version of the question ?

Comment: `?some_param[]=a&some_param[]=b` like this.

Comment: Ok. Let's take it for granted that I just have to use AJAX. One reason is that the parameters are dependent on user actions. For example, a user chooses from a set of messages

Answer (score 0):

You can do it with:

```
var newWindow = window.open();
newWindow.document.write(html_response);
```

But the browser will show a popup alert and you will need to allow it manually.

Working Example:

https://jsfiddle.net/hc3b38bu/